# How to give username and password to a mail through C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
 char *arg[3];
 arg[0] = "firefox";
 arg[1] = "http://www.gmail.com"; 
 arg[2] = '\0';
 execvp(arg[0],arg);
}
```

Through this program I opened gmail home page in a web browser. Instead of giving username and password in the web browser, I want to give through C program. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the Gmail API instead of screen-scraping the browser? http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

Comment: `arg[2]` should be `NULL` not `'\0'` (though they're both 0).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: I'm not sure how that is going to help with opening a browser & authenticating the users there.

Comment: I am not able to find in libcurl. can u tell in detail? I don't want authentication, Just get input as username and password in c program and that input to gmail website...

Comment: I read the second sentence as wanting to do everything from C, without a browser, but I see how your reading works too. In that case, I'd look at a framework like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). C is not a good language for browser automation, unless you are on Windows and building IE toolbars. *shudder*

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify:

Are you trying to automate the opening of Firefox to your Gmail account, or write a program to log into your Gmail account and automatically download information?

Comment: good question - it would be much easier to grab the email via IMAP.

Comment: no need of automatic download information. Just automation only

Comment: Then you're really looking at ways to automate Firefox from the command line.  I'm not sure that's possible today.

Answer (score 0):

It's not C, but you can probably do this using a test framework such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).